How to Loop through each element of a loop and filter out conditions in a python dataframe
I have a list of subcategories and a dataframe. I want to filter out the dataframe on the basis of each subcategory of the list.
lst = [7774, 29409, 36611, 77553]

import pandas as pd
data = {'aucctlg_id': [143424, 143424, 143424, 143388, 143388, 143430],
        'catalogversion_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.2],
'Key': [1434241, 1434241, 1434241, 1433881, 1433881, 14343012],
        'item_id': [4501118, 4501130, 4501129, 4501128, 4501127, 4501126],
'catlog_description': ['M&BP PIG IRON FA', 'M&BP PIG IRON FA', 'M&BP PIG IRON FA', 'PIG IRON MIXED OG','PIG IRON MIXED OG', 'P.S JAM & PIG IRON FINES'],
        'catlog_start_date': ['17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00','17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00'],
'subcategoryid': [29409, 29409, 29409, 7774, 7774, 36611],
        'quantity': [200, 200, 200, 180, 180, 100],
        'auctionable': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'Y' ,'Y']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

I have tried using the following code but I want output as a dataframe here it generates a list and of a single subcategory:
new=[]
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    mask1 = df['subcategoryid']==(lst[i])
    df2 = df.loc[mask1]
    new.append(df2)

Required Output files, with the filtered data:
df_7774, df_29409, df_36611


Just for clarity, when you say that you want output files, what should be the format? CSV?

Also, not that if you just want to filter the categories using lst you just need new_df = df[df['subcategoryid'].isin(lst)]

You could pre-filter with isin, then use groupby:
lst = [7774, 29409, 36611, 77553]

out = dict(list(df[df['subcategoryid'].isin(lst)].groupby('subcategoryid')))

Which will create a dictionary of the desired dataframes:
{7774:    aucctlg_id  catalogversion_id      Key  item_id catlog_description     catlog_start_date  subcategoryid  quantity auctionable
       3      143388                1.0  1433881  4501128  PIG IRON MIXED OG  17-05-2024  11:00:00           7774       180           Y
       4      143388                1.0  1433881  4501127  PIG IRON MIXED OG  17-05-2024  11:00:00           7774       180           Y,
 29409:    aucctlg_id  catalogversion_id      Key  item_id catlog_description     catlog_start_date  subcategoryid  quantity auctionable
        0      143424                1.0  1434241  4501118   M&BP PIG IRON FA  17-05-2024  11:00:00          29409       200           Y
        1      143424                1.0  1434241  4501130   M&BP PIG IRON FA  17-05-2024  11:00:00          29409       200           Y
        2      143424                1.0  1434241  4501129   M&BP PIG IRON FA  17-05-2024  11:00:00          29409       200           Y,
 36611:    aucctlg_id  catalogversion_id       Key  item_id        catlog_description     catlog_start_date  subcategoryid  quantity auctionable
        5      143430                1.2  14343012  4501126  P.S JAM & PIG IRON FINES  17-05-2024  11:00:00          36611       100           Y}

If you want to create files without intermediate:
lst = [7774, 29409, 36611, 77553]

for k, g in df[df['subcategoryid'].isin(lst)].groupby('subcategoryid'):
    g.to_excel(f'df_{k}.xlsx')


I want the output file in excel format.

@Ami then just replace to_csv by to_excel (see update). Use g.to_excel(f'df_{k}', index=False) if you don't want the index.

I used the above code but there's an extra ')' after the .groupby('subcategoryid')):
and it throws an error  No engine for filetype: ''

That's indeed a typo, you might need to add a valid extension see update. Also make sure you have the required libraries (pip install xlsxwriter)

import pandas as pd

lst = [7774, 29409, 36611]

data = {'aucctlg_id': [143424, 143424, 143424, 143388, 143388, 143430],
    'catalogversion_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.2],
    'Key': [1434241, 1434241, 1434241, 1433881, 1433881, 14343012],
    'item_id': [4501118, 4501130, 4501129, 4501128, 4501127, 4501126],
    'catlog_description': ['M&BP PIG IRON FA', 'M&BP PIG IRON FA', 'M&BP PIG IRON FA', 'PIG IRON MIXED OG', 'PIG IRON MIXED OG', 'P.S JAM & PIG IRON FINES'],
    'catlog_start_date': ['17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00', '17-05-2024  11:00:00'],
    'subcategoryid': [29409, 29409, 29409, 7774, 7774, 36611],
    'quantity': [200, 200, 200, 180, 180, 100],
    'auctionable': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
filtered_dfs = {}
for subcategory in lst:
    filtered_dfs[f'df_{subcategory}'] = df[df['subcategoryid'] == subcategory]
for key, value in filtered_dfs.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)


The output gives me dictionary. But I to download the output files in excel format.
